# How to create a C++ DLL using another C++ LIB?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, static-linking

I'm trying to generate a DLL based on existing software pieces compiled in a static library (.lib) file. I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and the target is purely Windows.

The existing project (**P1**) have the following function :

```cpp
int runLocal();
```

It's compiled to **P1.lib**.

In my new DLL project (**P2**), I have the following code :

```cpp
#include "..\path\to\P1.h"  // declaration of "int runLocal()"
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall DLLMain() {
    int res = runLocal();
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Project P2 (DLL) have following linker options :

- Additional dependencies: **D:\path\to\P1.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)**

However the linker "refuse" to see or use the lib file, and I get this error :
`LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall runLocal(void)" (?runLocal@@YGHXZ)`.
In fact, I get excatly the same error if  I didn't tell the linker to use `P1.lib` file.

I have control over all the project sources, so I can change stuffs where it's necessary.

- **Note 1:** The P2 project is used by a debug application (a third project compiled separately) that use `LoadLibrary()` to run the exported `DLLMain` function.
- **Note 2:** I already succeeded in compiling an exe file against the same .lib file using the same method. So the difference seems to be in the DLL generation.
- **Note 3:** I tried (without success) to play with many options in Visual project properties, in both compiler & linker section, at least the options that are not beyond my understanding.

So, what should I do to link correctly the .lib file and create my dll ?

#### Edit 1: I add the compiler & linker options:

- P1 compiler options:

```
/permissive- /GS /TP /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t
/I"C:\_tools\boost_1_68_0\" /I"C:\_tools\cryptopp_8_2_0\"
/Qspectre /guard:cf /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"tmp_Win32_Release\p1.pdb" /Zc:inline
/fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL"
/errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /std:c++17 /FC
/Fa"tmp_Win32_Release\" /EHsc /nologo
/Fo"tmp_Win32_Release\" /Ot /Fp"tmp_Win32_Release\p1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

- P1 librarian options:

```
/OUT:"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Common\p1.lib" /LTCG /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /NOLOGO
```

Checked with dumpbin.exe as suggested, and the symbol "*?runLocal@@YGHXZ*" exists in p1.lib

- P2 compiler options:

```
/permissive- /MP /GS /TP /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t
/I"C:\_tools\boost_1_68_0\" /I"C:\_tools\cryptopp_8_2_0\"
/Qspectre /guard:cf /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"tmp_Win32_Release\vc142.pdb"
/Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL"
/D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"
/errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gz /Oy /Oi /MD /std:c++17 /FC
/Fa"tmp_Win32_Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"tmp_Win32_Release\" /Ot
/Fp"tmp_Win32_Release\XL4DLL32.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

- P2 linker options:

```
/OUT:"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Release\XL4DLL32.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental
/NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Release\XL4DLL32.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE
"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Common\p1.lib" "D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Common\SharedToolsLib32.lib"
"kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib"
"advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"
"odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"
/IMPLIB:"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Release\XL4DLL32.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X86
/OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"D:\Projets\XL4DLL\Release\XL4DLL32.pgd"
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
/ManifestFile:"tmp_Win32_Release\XL4DLL32.dll.intermediate.manifest"
/OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO
/LIBPATH:"C:\_tools\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib" /TLBID:1
```

There is another difference between P1 and P2 projects configuration:

- P1 is configured to use "*Use MFC in a Shared DLL*"
- P2 is configured to use "*Use Standard Windows Libraries*", because it requires the use of Windows.h header and uses symbols not defined with MFC usage.

Comment: The settings you describe should work. Make sure that you are updating the properties of the same configuration you are building. Pay attention to the Active Configuration drop-down in the Properties dialog.

Comment: I agree that this configuration should work. Silly question but in the P1 project, did you write the content of the runLocal() in a cpp file ? That could explain your error

Comment: Use the dumpbin.exe tool to print out the symbols present in the static library.  Compare these symbols to the `?runLocal@@YGHXZ` one the linker is complaining about.

Comment: Ok, I already counter checked many times the vcproject settings, I only use the "Release/x86" target everywhere for the moment. @GRFRM yes, runLocal() is declared in the header but defined in a cpp file, that is compiled into P1.lib.

Comment: @BenVoigt I confirm the symbol exists in the static library.

Comment: Any possibility of a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch between the library and the program trying to use it?  The linker will ignore library files with the wrong architecture.

Comment: @BenVoigt After checking no, the loaded lib file is in the same architecture. I merged all the sources in a separate project and the compilation works. So it's not an issue of code compatibility between the projects.